# Positioning 2 divs next to eachother

Tags: html, css

iI'm a beginner thats why i couldn't find the answer because I don't have any idea what I need to use for the search terms.

Now I have a form

```
        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <div id="labels">
    <label>CMS Systeem</label><p>
    <label>Responsive Design</label><p>
    <label>Google Pakket+</label><p>
    <label>Google Ranking</label><p>
    <label>Slider/Diavoorstelling</label><p>
    <label>Social Media</label><p>

<div id="input">
<input type="text" name="pagina" value="1"><p>
Ja<input type="radio" name="cms" id="cmsja" value="ja"/> Nee<input type="radio" name="cms" value="nee" id="cmsnee" checked/><p />
Ja<input type="radio" name="Responsive" value="ja"/> Nee<input type="radio" name="Responsive" value="nee" checked/><p />
Ja<input type="radio" name="Googlep" value="ja"/> Nee<input type="radio" name="Googlep" value="nee" checked/><p />
Ja<input type="radio" name="Googletop" value="ja"/> Nee<input type="radio" name="Googletop" value="nee" checked/><p />
Ja<input type="radio" name="slider" value="ja"  /> Nee<input type="radio" name="slider" value="nee" checked/><p />
Ja<input type="radio" name="socials" value="ja" id="mediaja" /> Nee<input type="radio" name="socials" value="nee" id="medianee" checked/><p />
            </div>
    </form>
```

**I want**

```
#input {
      next to #labels instead of under #input

}
```

I had it fixed with `margin: -xxxpx;` but I have a idea that's not the good way to do that.

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/tAVGC/

Comment: Can you post your code to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something? I have no idea what you're trying to say you want.

Comment: Done http://jsfiddle.net/tAVGC/

Comment: There are numerous issues here. Your HTML isn't valid. Stray, unclosed `p` tags are **not** the right way to create line breaks. I can't read the language but it looks like maybe your bareword text like 'Ja' and 'Nee' are better candidates for `label` than what you have. You also never close your `div` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things:

Your `<div id="labels" >` needed a `</div>` closing tag.

Also, `<p>` tags need an open and closing tag, like this `<p></p>`

And you need to be consistent in EVERY element getting a `<p>` tag if that's how you're hoping to line them up.  Ideally, you would want the mark-up to be like this:

```
<label>CMS System</label><input type="radio" name="cms" />
```

So they would be side by side in HTML and visually.  If you need them in 2 separate `<div>` containers, though, try this :

http://jsfiddle.net/sk6gz/1/

There seems to be a discrepancy between them, so either add an extra `<p>` in the first or second `<div>` container so you get what I *believe* you are looking for.

Comment: I think the whole use of `p` tags here is contrary to semantic markup and misplaced. There are better ways to make line breaks, and closing them (making them empty paragraphs) is not the answer. Also, if you're using `p` "hoping to line them up", you are not following best practices, which would use CSS for this (preferably externally linked).

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you.  I would never have my mark-up this way, but I'm just trying to fulfill OP's request.

Comment: @RCNeil Yeah, you did good. Putting the things in `p`s doesn't make sense, but if that's what OP does, it's what he does.  PS, you should add an option for fixing the issue with floats, which leave the elements in flow so you don't have to manually set large margins to account for `position: absolute`.

Comment: I also don't want to argue but wanted to explain my point pedagogically, since that's how it's being discussed. If we start writing SO answers where we leave in bad practice, mistakes, or misunderstandings just because "OP did it", well, you can see how that goes down a slippery slope pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/BURR2/

```
#labels { float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
```

Also, close your tags.

As a side note about styling with ids, I'd recommend using classes instead.  [This article](http://css-tricks.com/a-line-in-the-sand/) by Chris Coyier is a good one, and links some other good resources.

Answer (score 0):

More elegant with less markup

```
label{
display:inline-block;
width:150px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tAVGC/10/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to make some kind of CMS?

First of all, to learn how to position elements with CSS, I would do some searches for the terms `css box model`. That should yield some good results explaining how to place elemenst next to each other.

Now to your problem at hand. I am guessing you want something like this:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8wPD/)

You first placed all the labels in the markup and then all the controls (radio buttons), but the key here is to group them together: label and control for each question:

```
<label>CMS Systeem</label>
Ja<input type="radio" name="cms" id="cmsja" value="ja"/> 
Nee<input type="radio" name="cms" value="nee" id="cmsnee" checked="checked" />
<br/>
```

I used a `<br/>` element here which is a bit quick and dirty. The aforementioned box model will give you much better control over positioning.

I also think that you should search for things like `html forms`

Lastly, as a beginner, a CMS might be a bit ambitious. Why not start out smaller?

Answer (score 0):

For form elements, this sort of thing can work well:

#### HTML:

```
<label>CMS System</label><input type="radio" name="cms" />
<label>Your feelings</label><input type="text" name="feelings" />
```

#### CSS:

```
label, input[type=text] { display:inline-block; text-align: right; }
label { width: 30%; margin-right: 2%; }
input, input[type=text] { width: 60%; }
```

The radio inputs don't need a width, but I threw in the text input to show how you might flesh this out for forms.

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/harveyramer/E7kSt/